# 404 não é possível encontrar o recurso

Tags: asp.net

Eu copiei uma solução de uma máquina para outra, resolvi todas as dependências, não contém erros de building,mas, todos os arquivos css, js, paginas e etc recebo um erro 404

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou executando a aplicação em modo debug!

Minha aplicação anteriormente, tinha a seguinte url localhost:25500/ideia/login.aspx

agora ela só funciona de seu tirar da url o /ideia localhost:25000/login.aspx
só que todos os arquivos estão referenciados na aplicação como href:/ideia/XPTO.jpg

Comment: Erro 404 é arquivo/página não encontrada. Qual seria o problema fora isso?

Comment: Qual é o caminho não encontrado?

Comment: eu atualizei a pergunta acho que da pra ter uma noção melhor do erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema adicionando /ideia/ ao diretorio virtural

Ticando a opção override application root URL

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]